The Side Channel automatically frozen for inactivity
Now, our side-channel has been frozen

This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity

We need to unlock it!

Nope, not yet Maarten Bodewes. Still cannot write something. This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added. 

I thought that I would be able to fix this by posting in the room as moderator, but seemingly not. It seems that only room owners can unfreeze. However, as mod I can add users to be room owners.
For that reason I've added myself and the most frequent user kelalaka to the rooms' owner list. The room is now unfrozen. Post a comment beneath this post if it happens again, then me or kelalaka can thaw.

On the site I moderate, the main chat room does not freeze, although the only messages are from Feeds (the chat user).

(I mean, there must be something else that avoids a chat room that is not for moderators is frozen.)

@avpaderno Well, a bot would be nice, even if we just put XKCD in there. Codereview has a few good ones too.

In that chat room, the last message from a feed has been posted 35 days ago. If it was just for that, the chat room would have been already frozen. I should check exactly when, but something changed, as I recall that in the past I unfroze the chat room, but I have not done that since... ages.

FYI: the mostly-recently active room on a site won’t freeze, but the “main” chat room isn’t actually treated in a special way, so that room could just be some comments that were moved to chat, unfortunately: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100519/134300
